# float (which is having 4bytes of memory) can hold long (which is having 8bytes of memory) value in Java. how?

Tags: java, long-integer

Here is the code snippet.

Please tell what algorithm used for this kind of holding large data using small memory area.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long longValue = 2147483649L;//which is 8bytes in memory
    float floatValue = 23f;//which is 4bytes in memory
    floatValue = longValue;
    System.out.println(floatValue);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: You can assign a long to a float but you will lose precision

Comment: There is a Java Puzzler for this very issue - it tries to loop using a float, and behold, the loop loops forever (as the number is skipped, or even better when `f + 1 == f` and the float simply stays put).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that a `float` can hold *some* of the `long` values. If it can fit into the `float` floating point representation. *Others* will lose precision or will be converted to a different number.

See this example:

```
long l = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(l); // Prints 2147483647

float f = l;
System.out.printf("%f", f); // Prints 2147483648.000000
```

As you can see converting 2147483647 to `float` lost precesion (became a "different" number). Even though the "test" number was a number that clearly fits into 4 bytes (even with signed representation) but it can't fit into a 4-byte `float` representation (it also uses some bits e.g. for exponent).

Floating point numbers are represented using the [IEEE 754](http://754r.ucbtest.org/standards/754xml.html) standard.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is the *precision* of the number. A 32bit floating point number in [standard IEEE representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) can take very large and very small values:

> ±1.18×10−38 to ±3.4×1038
>   precision: approx. 7 decimal digits

These large and small numbers are represented by splitting the number into the *mantissa* and the *exponent*. The mantissa is the part that stores "the actual number" (whereas the exponent only stores "how large the number is". And the mantissa for a 32bit float value has 23 bits.

This means that when your long value becomes too large (namely, larger than a value that can be represented with 23 bits), then two *different* `long` values will be converted into the same `float` value.

This can quickly (and convincingly) be checked with the following program:

```
public class LongAsFloat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float previousFloatValue = 0;
        for (long i=1; i<Long.MAX_VALUE; i++)
        {
            float floatValue = i;

            if (floatValue == previousFloatValue)
            {
                System.out.println("Got "+floatValue+" for "+i+" and "+(i-1));
                break;
            }
            previousFloatValue = floatValue;
            if (i % 10000L == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Checking "+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will eventually print

```
Got 1.6777216E7 for 16777217 and 16777216
```

And not coincidentally, 2<sup>24</sup> = 16777216 - just too large to be represented with 23 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code:

```
    long longValue = Long.MIN_VALUE + 1; // which is 8bytes in memory
    float floatValue = longValue; // which is 4bytes in memory
    System.out.println(longValue + " != " + (long) floatValue);
```

It will print: `-9223372036854775807 != -9223372036854775808`

A float (and a double) can store **any value** (even infinity) but the larger the value becomes, the less precise it can be kept because it is indeed kept in a limited amount of space.

For example try:

```
    float floatValue = (float) 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.9;
    System.out.println(floatValue);
```

It will print `Infinity`

Or this:

```
    float floatValue = (float)   9999999999999999999999999999990d;
    float floatValue2 = (float) 10000000000000000000000000000000d;
    System.out.println(floatValue + " = " + floatValue2);
```

Will print:

```
1.0E31 = 1.0E31
```